# When to reapply after UK refusal

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My cousin UK visit visa was refused with her one year old son and husband. The reason for her refusal is that she said they are traveling to visit her uncle and they will be spending 21 days. The Eco said she mentioned that she said she will spend 21 days and that spends 50,000 naira monthly on living expenses that they noticed that she spent more than 50000 in some month her bank statement. That her statement is inconsistent. Eco also said she said she will spend 1300 pound for her visit and her husband will support her with 200 pounds. Since her husband has been refused they are not convinced if she will get the 200 pounds. Her son was refused due to his parents refusal.
She wants to reapply, but how soon can she do that. And how can she change her personal circumstances[image]

Comment: I'm not sure they really care about how much she spends, but rather how much income they have available. How much do they both earn, and how much do they both spend, per month?

Comment: Please share the refusal letter if possible after removing the personal details

Comment: I have added the refusal letter

Comment: Your cousin can reapply as soon as she likes, but whenever she does so she will need to clarify her financial situation and explain the discrepancies identified in the refusal. Does this answer your question? [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: @traveller. Pls can you brief me what the refusal letter is saying and how she can adjust her circumstances. About her monthly expense of 50,000 NGN she used an average estimate because her monthly expense are not fixed there are certain month she spend upto to 110,000 NGN & there are certain month she spends below 50,000 NGN. But the eco refused like based on that. Also she plans on reapplying alone with her son and she also want to reduce the number of days from 21 days  to 10 days and also reduce the cost of her trip from 1300pounds to 800 pounds and not adding 200 pounds from her spouse

Comment: She can use the ‘additional information’ section at the end of the application or write a cover letter to explain her financial situation. Reapplying very quickly after a refusal can be a risky strategy because it can make it seem that the applicant is ‘desperate’ to get to the UK, leading the ECO to doubt that they are a genuine visitor. Personally I would wait say 3-6 months before reapplying. Is the ECO going to view a 10 day trip from Nigeria to the UK, probably requiring a period of quarantine/self-isolation, as credible?

Comment: But looking at the visa refusal, I steal can identify the reason for refusal. I think are just ripping people off dere visa fee. Becos I explained there financial circumstances with evidence. I also noted it that the 50000 is an average monthly expenses since her expenses per month varies. I also added extra 10 days quarantine to her proposed 11 day stay and noted it on the additional page. So y should dey refuse her on that bases.

Comment: @Luvly spot Does your cousin have any prior travel history, preferably to the UK or an equivalent destination eg Schengen/USA? If not, as well as a lack of travel history, the factors against her being granted a UK visa are a) her citizenship - Nigeria is deemed a high immigration risk b) family in the UK c) original intention to travel with her husband & child d) non-straightforward finances. The final section of the refusal indicates that the ECO was not convinced she is not an overstay risk

Comment: @Luvlyspot the visa was refused under Paragraphs 4.2 (a), (c), and (e). See this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e They aren't trying to, as you say, rip people off. They want a clear picture of your cousin's finances, which have not been provided to them. Also, they may have found problematic that your cousin claims to make ~2300 GBP yearly and was willing to spend more than half (1300 GBP) on a three week trip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: @jcm. I agree with your send reason of spending more than half of her yearly income on 21 days trip but but for your second reason I don't how else they want her to provide a clear picture of her finance.she is employed and also have her personal business. She provided her personal bank statement shows her monthly income from her work and business. She also provided her business account statement. I don't know what else they want.

Comment: @Luvlyspot did you read the questions Traveller and I linked? It's all in there. They want to see all inflows and outflows match with what you tell them. Any unexplained transactions (in or out) makes them suspicious and think that you may be hiding something. In this case your cousin's unexplained extra outflows. You can feel indignant and insist you don't understand the refusal or you can start reading, understanding, and planning your next move.

Comment: jcm. Am not been indignant but it's just that d refusal was painful. The 2300 gbp a yearly you mention is not her total year earning but her yearly earning from other income (her personal business). If u check the refusal letter u will see another 278.88 gbp monthly salary from her employer stated by eco. So her total yearly income is over 5600 gbp in a year. Don't knw why her husband 200gbp support should affect  her because she has enough money to cover up even if she doesn't get the 200gbp from him .I just want to understand d eco point 4 refusal  b4 reapplying to avoid another refusal.

Comment: ^ Your last comment illustrates it perfectly. The financial picture is not well-explained. This will be my last comment as the provided links should help you, if you wish it.

Comment: Typo in second bullet point under The decision  "... travelling you're your spouse and child". I wonder if this is just bad proofreading or if this notice could have been written by a visa agent and not an ECO.